# Android Fragment in Activity and isFinishing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

In my application i am using some fragments, in a viewpager.
I want to show a dialog in a fragment like this:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity, R.style.DialogTheme);
dialog.show();
```

The activity is set in the `onCreateView` like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        activity = getActivity();
}
```

This is working perfectly, but in some cases like if the app goes in background, and the user comes back to the app, i got an error "Fragment not attached to activity" in the line  "`dialog.show()`".

So to prevent this error i use this:

```
if(!activity.isFinishing())
   dialog.show();
else
   Toast.makeText(activity, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I think this is definitly not the best way...

Is there maybe a solution like reloading the app if the activity isFinishing or even a better solution?

Comment: Use `isAdded()` in Fragment to check . Dialog is not showing on User action so you have to check weather the fragment  is attached or not .

Comment: Where have you added the code to show dialog in your fragment and in what scenario you are showing the dialog? Also, it is bad practice to use activity variable. Instead directly use getActivity() everywhere.

Comment: Override onAttach() method rather than getActivity()

Comment: `ìsFinnishing()` should not be used for that. It's used when the activity is finnishing to tell if it's finnishing cause of user call to `finnish()` and not cause of the system destroying activity. see [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing())

Comment: So, i've have to check if the fragment is attached with the onAttach() function?! Do i have to check this in the fragment itself or the MainActivity? And what should i do, if the activity is not attached? Sorry,  a little bit confusing for me.

Comment: @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof MainActivity) {
            activity = (MainActivity) context;
        }
    }

Is this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

override onAttach method

```
@Override  
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {  
        super.onAttach(activity);  

        if (activity instanceof YourActiivty) {
               //here is your code
        } else {

        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
        @Override
        public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
            super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
            if (visible) {
                ...
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DialogFragment rather than showing dialog by Dialog class, it will give you more stable view ,just extend your class by "DialogFragment"

```
public class DemoDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

    public DemoDialogFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_demo_dialog, container, false);

                 -----------
        return rootView;
    }
```

and make function in you activity for calling it

```
public void showDialogFrag(DialogFragment dialogFragment, String tag) {
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), tag);
    }
```

Then call this function by this from any fragment

```
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).showDialogFrag(new DemoDialogFragment(), Constant.FragmentTags.DemoDialogFragment);
```